# Explain the output of the program in detail which uses 3D arrays?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Tell me how the output of the code below "3 6 1" gets generated?

```
int main()
{

int a[2][3][2]={{{1,2},{9,8},{3,7}},{{2,2},{1,4},{5,4}}};

printf("%d %d %d",a[1]-a[0],a[1][0]-a[0][0],a[1][0][0]-a[0][0][0]);

return 0;
}
```

I'm not getting how the elements are accessed for subtraction using just a[1] or a[0]. As it is a 3D array it should be accessed like a[0][1][2].Thank You.

Comment: I need it man. I'm self studying for an entrance exam and this is the only place where I can find answers to difficult questions.

Comment: Give all your input elements a unique value, and see what every type of operator does (i.e. what element is accessed by using a one-dimensional or a two dimensional accessor.). This way you learn how it works. Don't expect us to give you a free pass for your exam, just experiment and learn. If you cannot do that, programming is not for you.

Comment: Also, try printing the values of `a[1]` and `a[0]` and see what their values are. You might get a hint.

Comment: I tried to get the individual values of a[0] and a[1] but they are changing everytime!! Cant get where are the values coming from!! The values are very large as compared to input.

Comment: @WittyGeek79: They are very large because those are memory addresses. What's important is the difference between them. Subtract them to know how far apart the sub-arrays or variables are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may imaging it like:

a[0] and a[1] = 3 elements by 2 int (2-d arrays) (size of each = 2 * int)

a[0][0] and a[1][0] = 2 elements by int (size = int)

a[0][0][0] and a[1][0][0] = real int values, so they can be subtracted (2 - 1 = 1)

If compiler can't direct subtract values, then he "subtract structures" i. e. a[1] - a[0] = ((begin of a[1]) - (begin of a[0])) / sizeof(elements of a[0]) = (6 * int) / (2 * int) = 3

between a[1][0] and a[0][0] allocated 6 int's, so a[1][0] - a[0][0] = ((begin of a[1][0]) - (begin of a[0][0])) / sizeof(elements of a[0][0]) = (6 * int) / (1 * int) = 6

Some advices:

1) Use debugger and disassembler! Im just look asm code and see how its calculated.

2) Forget about so unclear way getting amount of elements between elements! Its very bad practice, just for stupid exam knowledge's.

P. S. sorry for bad English.. I tried write correctly, but could be mistakes somewhere.

Comment: I understood what you said @Green_Wizard. Thanks.
P.S. Your English is not that bad. :)